# Displaying properties in another page when plus ( + )button is clicked in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created react app. I have directory components with folder pages where I have FindAllMetadata component in which I am making GET request and getting all metadata from API. I am passing loadedMetadata to AllMetadataTable as props. AllMetadataTable component is located in other folder called data. There I am displaying some information about fetched metadata items in table ( Creator, Time Created, Format ) and other fetched properties I am not displaying. In a table aside of the every fetched metadata I have + button which when clicked makes link ( route ) to the new page where I want display all information about fetched metadata, single clicked metadata item. Details component is located in folder pages. I want to display clicked Metadata from AllMetadataTable in Details page or in Metadata component.

Here is my App.js :

```
    import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
    import {  Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import classes from './App.module.css'
    import LoadingSpinner from './components/UI/LoadingSpinner';
    import Layout from './components/layout/Layout';
    import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
    import RequestMenu from './components/UI/RequestMenu';


    // load components only when user gets to them
    const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/Dashboard'));
    const NewData = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/NewData'));
    const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/NotFound'));
    const FindAllReceivedRequests = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/FindAllReceivedRequests'));
    const FindAllGivenConsents = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/FindAllGivenConsents'));
    const ReadConsent = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/ReadConsent'));
    const FindData = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/FindData'));
    const FindAllMetadata = React.lazy(() => import ('./components/pages/FindAllMetadata'));
    const NewPartnerRequest = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/NewPartnerRequest'));
    const FindAllGivenRequests = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/FindAllGivenRequests'));
    const FindAllReceivedConsents = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/FindAllReceivedConsents'));
    const Metadata = React.lazy(() => import('./components/data/Metadata'));


   function App() {
    return (

    <BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>
      <Suspense fallback= { <div className = { classes.centered }> <LoadingSpinner /> </div> } >
        <Switch>

        <Route path ='/' exact>
          <Dashboard />
          <FindData />
        </Route> 

        <Route path= '/new-data' exact>
         <NewData />
        </Route>

        <Route path= '/metadata' exact>
         <FindAllMetadata />
        </Route>

        <Route path = '/data'>
         <Metadata />
          </Route> 

        <Route path= '/request' exact>
          <RequestMenu />
         <FindAllReceivedRequests />
         <section style = {{ marginTop: '5rem',
                            
                            }}>
         <FindAllGivenConsents />
         </section>
        </Route>

        <Route path= '/givenrequest' exact>
          <RequestMenu />
         <FindAllGivenRequests />
         <section style = {{ marginTop: '5rem',
                            
                            }}>
         <FindAllReceivedConsents />
         </section>
        </Route>

        <Route path= '/transfer-data' exact>
         <ReadConsent />
        </Route>

        <Route path= '/partner-request' exact>
         <NewPartnerRequest />
        </Route>

        <Route path= '*'>
          <NotFound />
        </Route>

          </Switch>
         </Suspense>
       </Layout>
       <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
     
     );
    }

    export default App;
```

Here is my FindAllMetadata.js where I am fetching allMetadata ( it is working ):

```
     import React, {  useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
     import AllMetadataTable from '../data/AllMetadataTable';
     import LoadingSpinner from '../UI/LoadingSpinner';
     import styles from '../UI/Messages.module.css';
     import styled from '../style/Form.module.css';
     import { readAllMetadata } from '../lib/api';


       const FindAllMetadata = () => {
        const [allMetadata, setAllMetadata] = useState([]);
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
        const [enteredMetadataFilter, setEnteredMetadataFilter] = useState('all');
  
         
                 // When page is loaded immediately fetch (and display) all metadata (only running the  effect when                   enteredMetadataFilter changes) 
       useEffect(() => {
        // fetch metadata by entered request filter (all or my) 
     const readAllMetadataHandler = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError(null);
      try {
        const loadedAllMetadata = await readAllMetadata(enteredMetadataFilter);
        setAllMetadata(loadedAllMetadata);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
      };
    readAllMetadataHandler();
    }, [enteredMetadataFilter]);

    // display fetched content
    const content = useMemo(() => {
    if (error) {
      return <div className={styles.negative}> { error.message } </div>;
    } else if (isLoading) {
      return <section style = {{margin : '1rem 17rem' }} ><LoadingSpinner /> </section>;
    } else {
      return  (
              <AllMetadataTable allMetadata = { allMetadata }
                                metadataFilter = { enteredMetadataFilter }
                                issLoading = { isLoading }
                />
          
        );
       }  
    }, [isLoading, error, allMetadata, enteredMetadataFilter]);

    return  (
        <>
        {/** pick filter for displaying metadata */}
        {!isLoading && 
        <section style= {{ marginLeft : '-10rem'}} >
          <select className={styled.selectControl}
                            onChange={ event => {
                                    setEnteredMetadataFilter(event.target.value);         
                            }} >
                                                                                                                


                       <option value='' disabled style={{ color: '#cccccc' }} > Choose an option      
                     </option>
                            <option value = 'all'> All Metadata </option>
                            <option value = 'my'> My Data </option>
                            </select> 
          
        </section>
        }
    <section>
      {/**display content by status: error, loading, allmetadata, mymetadata */}
        { content }
    </section>
        </>
      )
    }

    export default FindAllMetadata;
```

Here is my AllMetadataTable.js component where I am displaying fetched metadata in a table ( it is working and when I click + button it is redirecting me to correct URL ) :

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import "semantic-ui-css/components/table.min.css";
    //import Metadata from './Metadata';
    import classes from '../style/Form.module.css';
    import Time from '../time/time';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Metadata from './Metadata';

    const AllMetadataTable = ({ allMetadata, metadataFilter, issLoading }) => {
     const history = useHistory();
    // sorted by time created - newest first
    const allMetadataSorted = [...allMetadata].sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.TimestampCreated) - new Date(a.TimestampCreated);
     });
     // open details page for wanted metadata
    const openDetailsPage = (key) => {
    history.push({
              pathname: 'data',
              search: `?id=${allMetadata[key].DObjectId}`
      })
    }; 
  
    return (
    <>
    {!issLoading &&
    <Table celled fixed singleLine
            style={{
                width : '60rem',
                marginLeft: '-10rem',
                
            }} >
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Creator</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Host</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Domain</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Format</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Time Created</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell
          style={{
            width : '4rem',
        }}>Details</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>

      <Table.Body>
      {allMetadataSorted.map((metadata) => (
      <React.Fragment key={metadata.key}>
      <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>{metadata.OrgIdCreator}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{metadata.OrgIdHost}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{metadata.TagsDomain}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{metadata.DataFormatId}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{Time(metadata.TimestampCreated)}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
      {/** open/close metadata */}
      <Button className={classes.uichange}
               style ={{
               border: 'none',
               borderRadius: '0px',         
               color: 'white', 
               cursor: 'pointer', 
               backgroundColor: '#19a47c', 
               margin: '0 1rem',
               fontSize : 22 }}
               onClick={() => openDetailsPage(metadata.key) }>
                                        +
                                      </Button>

      </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
      </React.Fragment>
      ))}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
      }
       </>
       );
     };

    export default AllMetadataTable;`

Here is my Metadata.js component which I wanna show in a new page when + button in a table is clicked ( id I am getting is corrrect and it is displaying in a list correctly but all other fields are empty; how can I access other fields and display them ?) : 
    `import React from 'react';
     import classes from '../style/SingleData.module.css';
     import list from '../style/List.module.css';
     import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
     //import styles from '../UI/Messages.module.css';
     import LoadingSpinner from '../UI/LoadingSpinner';

     import Time from '../time/time';
     import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

     /** import ORG_NAME  */
     const ORG = process.env.REACT_APP_ORG_NAME;

    const Metadata = (props) => {
      const { search } = useLocation();
      const id = new URLSearchParams(search).get('id');
       console.log(id);
        // close metadata 
        const stopReadingDataHandler = () => {
          props.onClose()
        };

    return (
     <>
    <ul className={list.tableList} >
    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>  Data Id:  </strong> {id} 
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong> Doc Type Code: </strong> {props.DocTypeCode}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong> Data Format: </strong> {props.DataFormatId}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>Creator: </strong> {props.OrgIdCreator}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong> Host: </strong> {props.OrgIdHost}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>Tags Content: </strong> {props.TagsContent}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>Domain: </strong> {props.TagsDomain}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>Time Created: </strong> {Time(props.TimestampCreated)}
    </li>

    <li style={{ borderRadius: '0px' }} className={classes.data}>
      <strong>Time Updated: </strong> {Time(props.TimestampUpdated)}
    </li>

 

        { /** display Cancel button if you are Creator or Host */}
        {!props.isLoading && (props.OrgIdCreator === ORG || props.OrgIdHost === ORG) &&     props.transferCheckStatus === false ? 
              <div style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }} 
                    className={classes.Form__actions}>
                        <Button className={classes.uichangedelete}
                                   style ={{
                                            border: 'none',
                                            borderRadius: '3px',         
                                            color: 'white', 
                                            cursor: 'pointer', 
                                            backgroundColor: 'red', 
                                            margin: '10px',
                                            fontSize : 22 }} 
                                            type= 'button'
                                            content='Cancel'
                                            onClick={ stopReadingDataHandler }
                                            /> 
              </div>
                    : null }
                
                      {/** display loading spinner if loading */}
                      {props.isLoading && <LoadingSpinner />}
                     
          </ul>
       </>
      );
    };

    export default Metadata;
```

I tried using props inside FindAllMetadata, inside AllMetadataTable; I created other page Details.js in same folder as `FindAllMetadata ( pages folder` ) ; I tried `useHistory`, `useLocation`, `useParams` etc. `

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

In your openDetailsPage function you are passing only the id to the Metadata component:

*const openDetailsPage = (key) => {
history.push({
pathname: 'data',
search: `?id=${allMetadata[key].DObjectId}`
})
};*

You are using history.push method with the following parameters:

1. pathname => which is '/data/ for Metadata component
2. search => query to url (NOTE: Here you are passing only the id)
   Try adding:
3. state => an object to pass to the Metadata components:

history.push({

```
      pathname: 'data',
      search: `?id=${allMetadata[key].DObjectId}`,
      state: {item: allMetadata[key]}
```

})

Then access it on the Metadata component by using:
**props.location.state.item**